# powershell questions about active directory access

Tags: powershell, active-directory

so,

I have to get users in an AD, but there are two.

AD1
AD2

how does this know in which it should go?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=place,DC=AD1,DC=somethingthesame,DC=com
```

I'm rly bad at making a template address.

So, my intuition is that the triple "DC" are unique and that's how it knows where to go, but can someone confirm?

also why does it not require logs to get in?

ps: as far as the command is concerned it works properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To query a specific domain the most reliable way is probably to use the `-Server` switch to direct the query to that domain:

```
Get-ADUser -Server AD1DomainController.mydomain.com -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=place,DC=AD1,DC=somethingthesame,DC=com
```

Environments vary and so the way you choose a Domain controller will too. In many enviroments simply using the domain name will return a domain controller. In others you might have to query to find one

Comment: do I need to input login info with this? when I run my command I get an "unable to connect error message" or "unable to contact server" its in French so I don`t know the full translation.

Comment: Unless you current login has the permissions, you need to provide credentials for the domain you're trying to query see `-Credential` switch and the `Get-Credential` command

Comment: so, rn the credential approach doesn't give me issues, but the -server part of the command does. for some reason it doesn't see the server. removing it default to the server 1. I have no idea why it doesn't work since the line worked on the first server.
I`ll post another question with more details